# Передача в функцию указателя на массив структур, член которой представляет собой символьный массив

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Возник вопрос, как передать в функцию указатель на массив структур для обработки члена структуры (в данном случае strcmp()), который являет собой строку. Ниже привожу решение, которое выглядит несколько коряво, но работает корректно. Буду рад увидеть более изящные решения (как надо) или узнать о статьях/книгах, где более подробно освещается вопрос передачи указателя на массив структур в функции. Заранее спасибо!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 20
#define MAX_LEN_S 4

struct months
{
    char name[MAX_LEN];
    char name_s[MAX_LEN_S];
    int month_num;
    int month_len;
};

int sum_days_with_mn(const struct months (*months_in_y)[], int day, char *m_n);

int main(void){
    const struct months months_year[12] = {
        {"january", "jan", 1, 31}, 
        {"february", "feb", 2, 28},
        {"march", "mar", 3, 31},
        {"april", "apr", 4, 30},
        {"may", "may", 5, 31},
        {"june", "jun", 6, 30},
        {"july", "jul", 7, 31},
        {"august", "aug", 8, 31},
        {"september", "sep", 9, 30},
        {"october", "oct", 10, 31},
        {"november", "nov", 11, 30},
        {"december", "dec", 12, 31}
    };

    const struct months *ps;
    ps = &months_year[0];
    printf("2. %d\n", sum_days_with_mn(ps, 31, "mar"));

    return 0;
}

int sum_days_with_mn(const struct months (*months_in_y)[1], int day, char *m_n){
    int i, sum;
    sum = i = 0;

    while(strcmp(months_in_y[i]->name_s, m_n) != 0){
        sum += months_in_y[i++]->month_len;
    }
    sum += day;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Так а в чем состоит задание-то? Что эта функция должна делать?

Comment: Функция считает количество дней с начала года. Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Действительно, должно быть я слишком перемудрил.

Answer (score 1):

Если размер вашего массива структур не является заранее фиксированным (т.е. предзаданным на стадии компиляции), то использовать тип "указатель на массив" вам ни к чему. Используйте обычный указатель на структуру

```
int sum_days_with_mn(const struct months months_in_y[], int day, const char *m_n)
{
  int i = 0, sum = 0;

  while (strcmp(months_in_y[i].name_s, m_n) != 0) {
    sum += months_in_y[i++].month_len;
  }

  sum += day;
  return sum;
}

...
sum_days_with_mn(months_year, 31, "mar")
```

Однако в вашем случае сама природа задачи подразумевает массив предзаданного размера `12`. В такой ситуации уместнее, может быть, использовать именно указатель на массив

```
int sum_days_with_mn(const struct months (*months_in_y)[12], int day, const char *m_n)
{
  int i = 0, sum = 0;

  while (strcmp((*months_in_y)[i].name_s, m_n) != 0) {
    sum += (*months_in_y)[i++].month_len;
  }

  sum += day;
  return sum;
}

...
sum_days_with_mn(&months_year, 31, "mar")
```

Константу `12` лучше поименовать. Например

```
#define N_MONTHS_PER_YEAR 12
```

Цикл с "открытым" условием завершения, т.е. рассчитывающий, что месяц `m_n` обязательно найдется - не самая лучшая идея. Лучше было бы предусмотреть ситуацию, когда по какой-то причине найти месяц `m_n` не удалось, и останавливать поиск по достижению конца массива. В первом случае размер массива придется передавать в функцию извне, а во втором он и так известен.

**P.S.** Ваш текущий вариант "работает корректно" только из-за набора вопиющих и бессмысленных подтасовок. Это как раз тот случай, когда в программе содержится "четное количество багов" и они точно компенсируют друг друга.

Comment: Это была черновая версия. Мне главное было понять, как передавать структуру. Но все равно спасибо.